# get value from select box to text box

Tags: jquery

```
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:red; margin:4px; }
  b { color:blue; }
  </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><input type="text" name="keyword" /></p>
  <select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>

    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>
<script>
    function displayVals() {
      var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
      $("p").html("<b>Multiple:</b> " + 
                  multipleValues.join(", "));
    }

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();

</script>
```

Here I want to hold value in a text box instead of "p".
How to do it??
Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Nv52J/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayVals() {
      var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
      var html = $("p").html();
      $("p").html("<b>Multiple:</b>" + html);

        $("input[name='keyword']").val( multipleValues.join(", "));
    }

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with input you should use jQuery.val() (http://api.jquery.com/val/). Something like this
    $("p").val("**Multiple:** " + multipleValues.join(", "));
But no tag inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="foooooooooo" />
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
<option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
<option>Multiple2</option>
<option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
</select>
```

//////////////////////

```
 function displayVals() {

  var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
    var text = "Multiple: " + multipleValues.join(", ");
  $("input").val(text);
 }

$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Javascript

```
function displayVals() {
  var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
  $("#result").val("<b>Multiple:</b> " +
              multipleValues.join(", "));
}

$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="result" ></input>
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
<option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
<option>Multiple2</option>
<option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
</select>`
```